# PHP Populating an Array of Associated Array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through some results list that contains information about fruit and who has picked.

Each iteration contains a single fruit and a single person who picked it.

```
foreach($Jobs as $key => $val) {

//set values
$fruit = $val->FruitName;
$picker = $val->Picker->ForeName;

//build my array here
$myArray[$val->FruitName] = $val->Picker->ForeName;

}
```

I'm trying to build up an associative array (using fruit names) that holds an array of the picker names, like so;

```
$myArray = array (
"apple" => array ("Jon","Jo","Dave"),
"pear" => array ("Ben"),
"plumb" => array ("Jane"),
"melon" => array ("Jon","Jo","Dave","Sarah"),
);
```

The way I'm currently attempting this simply overwrites the existing array of picker names.

Comment: `$myArray[$val->FruitName][] = $val->Picker->ForeName;`

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    foreach($Jobs as $key => $val) {

        //set values
        $fruit = $val->FruitName;
        $picker = $val->Picker->ForeName;

        //build my array here
        $myArray[$val->FruitName][] = $val->Picker->ForeName;
    }
```

Using your example you need to add the [] to the build array line. This is so the names are added to the array rather than overwriting the value.